# Regarding the UnsupportedOperationException in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i had used cascade="all-delete-orphan" in *.hbm.xml file i am getting the following exception can you pls tell how to resolve this

RegisteredSyn E   WTRN0074E: Exception caught from before_completion synchronization operation: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup$TransactionManagerAdapter$TransactionAdapter.setRollbackOnly(WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.CacheSynchronization.setRollbackOnly(CacheSynchronization.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.CacheSynchronization.beforeCompletion(CacheSynchronization.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup$1.invoke(WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup.java:142)
    at $Proxy1.beforeCompletion(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.jtaextensions.SynchronizationCallbackWrapper.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackWrapper.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.RegisteredSyncs.distributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TransactionImpl.prePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:2109)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TransactionImpl.stage1CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1538)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:1372)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:231)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:156)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.commit(TranStrategy.java:716)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:564)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:3798)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:3620)

Comment: You already asked this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667808/regarding-the-unsupportedoperationexception-in-hibernate).  Asking it again isn't going to help your case.

Answer (score 1):

this happen sometimes when you try to access a read-only property, or you are using a collection class when only a LinkedList will do.